# Using routing (?) to make GET request in Rails so ID doesn't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link in one view `myapp/locations` that goes to `myapp/statistics?id=1` (statistics for location with ID `1`) which works fine but it doesn't look pretty.  I think I've seen people do this sort of thing without needing the `?id=1`?  I could use a `POST` but this is not RESTful.  Is there a way I can use routing to allow the user to go to `myapp/statistics?id=1` but have the user see `myapp/statistics`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it go to myapp/locations/1/statistics(which is the rails way) if you scope statistics with locations in your route

```
resources :locations do
  resources :statistics
end
```

Comment: Would suggest swapping "namespace" for "resources", see my proposed edit for details.  The rest is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check out friednly_id gem. It makes it easier for you to have something like this: myapp/statistics/Germany.
Check out [Railscasts video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) about this gem.